# DbSet does not contain a definition for AddorUpdate

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Can anyone help with this?

```
 public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
  {
    #region Argument Validation

    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    }

    #endregion

    DbSet.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Id, entity);
    SaveChanges();

}
```

Getting error as "DbSet does not contain a definition for AddorUpdate?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an alternate way to solve this.

```
  public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
  {   if (entity == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

 this.DbContext.Update(entity);  
 this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method AddOrUpdate does not exist in Entity Framework Core. There are some issues on ef core github about it:
[Merge/Upsert/AddOrUpdate support](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4526)
[Another issue that has information that it will be added in the future.](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13575#issuecomment-429460926)